# How do I render an htm file in a razor component?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have quite a few htm files that were created for a helpdesk.  I'm trying to render these files into a fragment (One selected file).  This is displaying the html instead of rendering the html. There is certainly a more direct and simpler way to do this. This is what I have tried but all of the html is showing instead of the rendered html.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
<div>
    @(new HtmlString(content))
</div>

@code {

    private string fileName = @"wwwroot/HelpDocs\691_New Booking.htm";
    private string content = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }
}
```

There may be a better approach.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can try <div>@((MarkupString)content)</div> instead

Comment: @jeb That helped tremendously. However, there are image references in the original file that are not showing up.  Is there anyway to just display the file?

Comment: If the image references are not coming in, its probably a pathing issue. How are the references for the images written in the htm files? You can also inspect the rendered page from the running application with debugger tools in your web browser, which should help you figure out the issue

Comment: @Narish I'm sure you are correct.  The file will display correctly if opened in a browser.  However, when opened in the Blazor Component (just rendered), the references are not correct. It's like I need to position myself in the root directory to access the supporting files.

Comment: That's interesting....If you are able to alter the HTM files then you can probably tweak the pathing until you get it down. If you cannot alter those files, I'm guessing that you should inspect the path as it is evaluated and templated in at runtime (as in, what is literally written out when you inspect the element in the browser w debug tools), and then create that structure within your solution and move the images there

Comment: Generally speaking in ASP.NET, any sort of non-hardcoded pathing does start from the root directory, but Razor provides the `~/` syntax for relative pathing to make things easier. It begins from the root